Estimating the alpha-support of a distribution
I want to estimate the $\alpha$-support ($S_{α}$) of a distribution, which is the minimum volume subset of the support $S$ of a probability distribution $P$ ($S= supp(P)$), that supports a probability mass of $\alpha$: $S_{α} = min[V(s)]$ such that $P(s)=\alpha$.
For example, for a normal distribution with mean=0 and standard deviation sigma=1, the minimum volume set covering 68% of the total probability mass is the interval [-sigma, sigma]=[-1, 1].
How can this be done in python (for example just for one-dimensional data)?

Hello, if i'm not wrong, such sets are of the form ${x : f(x) > t }$ for some appropriate treshold $t$ and where $f$ is the density of the distribution. So, if you can find the value $t$ anatically, you're done, if not, you could try to find the appropriate value by an iterative algorithm.
